# Alter a column to perform onDelete('restrict') when foreign key is also primary key of self table for Laravel migrations

Tags: sql, laravel, migration

I have two table (**tbl_Traditional_Policysummery_KYC **& **tbl_UnderwritingWorkSheetInfo**) both table's primary key is **PolicyNo**

I want to restrict the delete operation of table **tbl_Traditional_Policysummery_KYC **when tbl_UnderwritingWorkSheetInfo has value with the same **PolicyNO**

I'm using MSSQL.

I have tried these migrations

```
$table->string('PolicyNo')->unsigned()->index()->change();
            $table->foreign('PolicyNo')
                ->references('PolicyNo')->on(with(new WorksheetInfo)->getTable())
                ->onDelete('restrict');
```

```
<?php

use App\Models\PolicySummaryKYC;
use App\Models\WorksheetInfo;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

class AddForeignKeyConstaintToKYCTable extends Migration
> {
>     /**
Run the migrations.
*
* @return void
*/
public function up()
>     {
Schema::table(with(new PolicySummaryKYC)->getTable(), function (Blueprint $table) {
>             $table->string('PolicyNo')->unsigned()->index()->change();
>             $table->foreign('PolicyNo')
>                 ->references('PolicyNo')->on(with(new WorksheetInfo)->getTable())
>                 ->onDelete('restrict');
>         });
>     }

>     /**
Reverse the migrations.
*
* @return void
*/
public function down()
>     {
Schema::table(with(new PolicySummaryKYC)->getTable(), function (Blueprint $table) {
>             //
>         });
>     }
> }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what you need to set inside your migration up()

```
Schema::table('tbl_Traditional_Policysummery_KYC', function (Blueprint $table) {
  $table->foreign('PolicyNo')
     ->references('PolicyNo')
     ->on('tbl_UnderwritingWorkSheetInfo')
     ->onDelete('restrict');
});
```

Note:

- I presume you already create another migration earlier to `tbl_Traditional_Policysummery_KYC` where inside you have declare `PolicyNo` as string and primary key ( `$table->string('PolicyNo')->primary();` )
- no need to add `unsigned()` to field type `string()` , it is meant for integer only, your PolicyNo field is string
- because PolicyNo field is already a primary, no need to be indexed
- to get table_name , you can use `(new App\Models\ModelName)->getTable()`, no need to use `with(...)` outside Model class

Comment: Not working . showing this message :  SQLSTATE[42000]: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'restrict'. (SQL: alter table "tbl_Traditional_Policysummery_KYC" add constraint "tbl_traditional_policysummery_kyc_policyno_foreign" foreign key ("PolicyNo") references "tbl_UnderwritingWorkSheetInfo" ("PolicyNo") on delete restrict)

Comment: aha you never tell in your question that you use ms sql , can you please update your question, thanks

Comment: not sure how can you achieve this on ms sql, because by default there as far as i know ON DELETE is by default RESTRICT ... perhaps write as db raw statement but without the last word 'restrict'